# Adding posts with thumbnail programmatically in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I know I can use the `wp_insert_post()` function in WordPress to add posts programmatically, but I want to add posts with a thumbnail, and for that matter, also resize/crop the post photo to the correct WordPress sizes.

Is all this possible programmatically, or do I need to do some work manually (i.e. the resizing/cropping)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out `wp_insert_attachment()`, found in wp-includes/post.php ([Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)).

So you create your post first using `wp_insert_post()`, then attach the file, somewhat like this (modified the Codex):

```
<?php 
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post_data ); 

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
?>
```

Regarding image resizing/cropping, if you go to your media settings (yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-media.php), you can define custom sizes for your images. Probably not as robust as you're looking for, but if you integrate the output with something like the [TimThumb Script](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/), you may get close to what you're looking for.

To see all the variables that the function has, read the commented info in post.php.

Answer (score 5):

After you insert the post and the attachment using wordpress' wp_insert_post and wp_insert_attachment functions, you can add the thumbnail to the post using the _thumbnail_id with the attachment's id, as long as your theme supports post thumbnails.

```
// $post_id = wp_insert_post(...)
// $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment(...)

add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id, true);
```

This way you'll be able to use wordpress default functions for thumbnail resizing and such.