# How to upload and add image to WP gallery programmatically?

Tags: image, wordpress, curl, upload

I need to upload image to WP gallery from server side. So PHP script (in cron) must do the job without my interaction. So I wonder if WP has built in feature for this or should I upload image with CURL to server first and then use some WP functions to add image to post and associate it with post ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding posts with thumbnail programatically in WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674069/adding-posts-with-thumbnail-programatically-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress v3.5 now has some great drag and drop functionality for doing bulk image uploads. Your post seems to imply an automated process where a human wont be involved.

There are 2 articles that have been written since your question was asked. Both provide slightly different solutions to your issue.  I hope these help someone:

Programmatically importing thousands of featured image post thumbnails into WordPress
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/diy-it/programmatically-importing-thousands-of-featured-image-post-thumbnails-into-wordpress/118

How To: Upload Media via URL Programmatically in WordPress
http://theme.fm/2011/10/how-to-upload-media-via-url-programmatically-in-wordpress-2657/